# New Azure Management Portal not showing all services

Tags: azure

I've logged into the new Azure management portal at https://manage.windowsazure.com but its only showing my databases and default directory. Its missing my WebApps, Groups etc.

The old portal at https://portal.azure.com/# is working fine.

Anyone else having this problem or know how to get everything appearing in the new portal?

Thanks.

Comment: You have things switched: `manage.windowsazure.com` is the old portal. `portal.azure.com` is the new portal. Regardless: This isn't a programming question.

Comment: Thanks! {embarassed} :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New portal is [portal.azure.com](https://portal.azure.com/) and old portal is [manage.windowsazure.com](https://manage.windowsazure.com).

In new portal you have option to create [ARM-based](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-overview/) services in new portal. Resource Manager isn't implemented in the old portal and that is why you don't see these resources.

Comment: Thanks! {embarassed} :)

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The new portal does *not* use Azure Resource manager for everything. It uses both legacy services and ARM-based services.

Comment: Thanks David! I corrected answers. "Everything" was wrong word.